# Mageia-Linux x86_64 Error: exec shell C code with static compilation

Tags: c, shell, gcc, libc, mageia

I am trying to exec a shell in C using the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    char *name[2];
    name[0] = "/bin/sh";
    name[1] = NULL;
    execve(name[0],name,NULL);
    return(0);
}
```

To compile this, I am using the gcc -static flag:

```
gcc -static -o shell shell.c
```

However, I get the following error:

```
/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

So far, I have tried to run : `ld -lc --verbose` and here's what I've found:

```
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-mageia-linux-gnu/lib64/libc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-mageia-linux-gnu/lib64/libc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libc.a failed
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing (at least) a static version of the `glibc`. If you really want to link statically (I assume dynamic linking, without the `-static` flag, would work? Why do you *want* to link statically here?) -- you will have to find out which package contains the `libc.a` file needed for that on your distribution.

On the other hand, if compiling never works, regardless of `-static` or not, you're missing development packages, something called typically `libc-dev`, `libc-devel`, `glibc-dev`, `glibc-devel` or something similar, it really depends on your distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use -static, you need to install glibc-static-devel.